How to Display Exactly 7 Bars at Once in SwiftUI Chart?
I'm working with SwiftUI's Chart and I want to display exactly 7 bars at once on the screen. Currently, with the following code snippet, I'm only able to see 3 bars at a time on my iPhone 11, and I want to adjust this so that 7 bars are visible simultaneously.
Here is my current implementation:
Chart(somethings, id: \.id) { something in
    BarMark(
        x: .value("Shape Type", something.tag.date, unit: .day),
        y: .value("Total Count", something.tag.duration)
    )
    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Tag", something.tag))
}
.chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)


I suspect that the issue might be related to the chart's horizontal scroll behavior or the way the bars are being rendered. How can I adjust my code to ensure that exactly 7 bars are shown at once without needing to scroll?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.
Show the code that produces the 3 bars, some code we can compile and run.
Have you tried giving your Chart a specific .frame(width: xxx, height: yyy), or .chartXAxis, or .chartXVisibleDomain.

chartXVisibleDomain is the modifier that you need.
For categorical data (i.e. if the x values are strings), you just need to pass in 7 to mean "7 bars at a time".
However, you seem to have Dates as the x values. In that case, 7 means "7 seconds at a time". Since each bar represents one day, you need to pass 86400 * 7.
Here is a complete example:
struct ChartData: Identifiable {
    let date: Date
    let duration: TimeInterval
    
    var id: Date { date }
}

let data = [
    ChartData(date: .now, duration: 1),
    ChartData(date: .now.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 1), duration: 1),
    ChartData(date: .now.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 2), duration: 2),
    ChartData(date: .now.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 3), duration: 3),
    ChartData(date: .now.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 4), duration: 4),
    ChartData(date: .now.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 5), duration: 5),
    ChartData(date: .now.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 6), duration: 6),
    ChartData(date: .now.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 7), duration: 7),
    ChartData(date: .now.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 8), duration: 8),
    ChartData(date: .now.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 9), duration: 9),
    ChartData(date: .now.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 10), duration: 10),
]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data) { x in
            BarMark(
                x: .value("X", x.date, unit: .day),
                y: .value("Y", x.duration)
            )
        }
        .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
        .chartXVisibleDomain(length: 7 * 86400)
    }
}

